# Error trying to install Docker in Windows Server 2016 with Install-Module

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, environment-variables, windows-server-2016

i'm trying to install Docker in a Windows Server 2016 without success:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Module -Name "DockerMsftProvider" -Force -Verbose
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: The -Repository parameter was not specified.  PowerShellGet will use all of the registered repositories.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/' and PackageManagementProvider is
'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='DockerMsftProvider'' for
 ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'DockerMsftProvider'.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Install-Module" on target "Version '1.0.0.1' of module 'DockerMsftProvider'".
VERBOSE: The installation scope is specified to be 'AllUsers'.
VERBOSE: The specified module will be installed in 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'NuGet' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Downloading module 'DockerMsftProvider' with version '1.0.0.1' from the repository
'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='DockerMsftProvider'' for
 ''.
VERBOSE: InstallPackage' - name='DockerMsftProvider',
version='1.0.0.1',destination='C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\1514242672'
VERBOSE: DownloadPackage' - name='DockerMsftProvider',
version='1.0.0.1',destination='C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\1514242672\DockerMsftProvider\DockerMsftProvider.nup
kg', uri='https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1'
VERBOSE: Downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1'.
VERBOSE: An error occurred while sending the request.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1' for '2' more
times
VERBOSE: An error occurred while sending the request.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1' for '1' more
times
VERBOSE: An error occurred while sending the request.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1' for '0' more
times
VERBOSE: Downloading package 'DockerMsftProvider' failed, please make sure
'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1' is accessable.
WARNING: Source Location 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1' is not valid.
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Package 'DockerMsftProvider' failed to download.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.1.3.1\PSModule.psm1:1827 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Users\943397...tProvider.nupkg:String) [Install-Package], Excep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PackageFailedInstallOrDownload,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPac
   kage
```

When o try to access the URL by IE it looks like charm, 
i'm behind corporative proxys and firewalls and didn't any network configurations.

EDIT: using this i resolved the error but get another one

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
$webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$creds=Get-Credential
$webclient.Proxy.Credentials=$creds
```

now i get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Find-Package –providerName DockerMsftProvider
WARNING: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json'
 because it does not exist.
WARNING: Save-HTTPItem: Bits Transfer failed. Job State: BG_JOB_STATE_ERROR ExitCode = 0
```

Suggestions?

EDIT 2: Guys, Setting the env variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY works for me
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Comment: IE may be configured to correctly go through the proxies, while PowerShell is not. Does `Invoke-WebRequest https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1` work? If not, the error should give you a clue.

Comment: Doesn't work:
Invoke-WebRequest : Bad Request.

How can i make my PowerShell to work with proxy configurations?

Answer (score 6):

I tried all above solution but I could not get it work until I run this command

```
   set-executionpolicy unrestricted
```

Finally following steps worked for me:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
 
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
 
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force

Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
Restart-Computer -Forc
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. DockerMsftProvider is deprecated.
This is a new guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34701274)

Comment: This is a Microsoft document. When the link becomes invalid, the answer will certainly become invalid too.

Comment: The link contains three independent ways to solve the problem at once: DockerCE/Moby, Mirantis Container Runtime and Containerd.

Answer (score 1):

This is very classic. After executing `Invoke-WebRequest https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/DockerMsftProvider/1.0.0.1` I immediately saw the issue: `Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`.

I guess they started enforcing SSL/TLS v1.2.

Run this in the same session on machines that still doesn't default to using TLS1.2:
`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

After this cmds like `Install-Module -Name "DockerMsftProvider" -Force -Verbose` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below command in Powershell as admin

1. [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
2. Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet
3. Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force
4. Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [manual install](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/docker-ee/#use-a-script-to-install-docker-ee).

Comment: check my Edition

Answer (score 0):

I tried below steps to be completed.

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force

Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force

Restart-Computer -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above work for me, since `DockerMsftProvider` is deprecated.

I ended up using chocolatey to install docker as the process doesn't allow the machine to reboot during processing.

Use `choco install docker` to install docker on the Windows server 2016 machine.

Related links:

- [The issue is pointed out in this thread](https://github.com/OneGet/MicrosoftDockerProvider/issues/14).
- [How to install docker on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1)
- [MicrosoftDockerProvider](https://github.com/OneGet/MicrosoftDockerProvider).

Answer (score 0):

Unfrotunately, none of the solutions worked for me, and I have found during my search at [microsoft qa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1324697/install-package-docker-windows-server-2022-error) that

> service has been shut down since May 23rd 2023

And you have to follow instruction on [MicrosoftDockerProvider](https://github.com/OneGet/MicrosoftDockerProvider) repo, which will forward you again to [Microsoft instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1).

Here is my footage:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/Main/helpful_tools/Install-DockerCE/install-docker-ce.ps1" -o install-docker-ce.ps1
>> .\install-docker-ce.ps1
Querying status of Windows feature: Containers...
Feature Containers is already enabled.
DOCKER default
Checking Docker versions
Downloading https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/docker-24.0.6.zip to C:\Users\mostafa\DockerDownloads\docker-24.0.6.zip
Installing Docker... C:\Users\mostafa\DockerDownloads\docker-24.0.6\docker\docker.exe
Installing Docker daemon... C:\Users\mostafa\DockerDownloads\docker-24.0.6\docker\dockerd.exe
Configuring the docker service...
Waiting for Docker daemon...
Successfully connected to Docker Daemon.
The following images are present on this machine:
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE

Script complete!
```

Then I was able to pull my first image ([Run your first docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container))

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
ltsc2022: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
452f3ad1d32c: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6562c9a2580260e4f2e3a081cc2cf1d960899cbce7c4568fb851e4848ca50e07
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
```

Good luck.

PS. I was working on windows server 2022, and I needed to enable `Container` feature, following this [link](https://computingforgeeks.com/using-docker-docker-compose-on-windows-server/)